# X path for bold tag

Tags: c#, xpath

```
<div id="ProductSummary_divMfgLink" class="pr-summary-sec">
    <b>   
    Manufacturer:
         <a id="ProductSummary_anchorMfgLink" class="standardText"
            style="font-size:12px;"
          href="http://www.rakuten.com /SR/SearchResults.aspx?mfgid=-2188">
     Asus
        </a>
   </b>
<meta content="Asus" itemprop="brand"></meta>
</div>
```

I  have to select the **Manufacturer:** name as **Asus**. Can Any one suggest me how to write xpath for this.

**I tried like this** I am new to this topic

```
var tag = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode
 ("//div[@id='ProductSummary_divMfgLink')and ./b[contains(.,'Manufacturer:')]]");
      if (tag != null)
     wi.Name = tag.InnerText.Trim();
```

Comment: Typo? this XPath should work fine : `//div[@id='ProductSummary_divMfgLink' and ./b[contains(.,'Manufacturer:')]]`